# Intermittent but frequent ORA-03135

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I am running an Oracle 12c application on 64-bit Windows 2016 VM.  The application connects via TNS using a 32-bit Oracle ODBC connection.  Intermittently but frequently I get ORA-03135 errors.
Having read many posts about this I have tried a lot of things i.e. Turning on/off connection pooling, setting SQLNET.EXPIRE_TIME, SQLNET.INBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, SQLNET.SEND_TIMEOUT, SQLNET.RECV_TIMEOUT etc. but nothing solves the issue.
I have managed to create a trace file that shows details of the error which appears to be a network issue.  Can anyone out there tell me what it means and how I can resolve it?

2018-07-26 13:20:36.561 : nsdofls:sending NSPTDA packet

2018-07-26 13:20:36.561 : nspsend:entry

2018-07-26 13:20:36.561 : nspsend:plen=33, type=6

2018-07-26 13:20:36.561 : nttwr:entry

2018-07-26 13:20:36.561 : ntt2err:entry

2018-07-26 13:20:36.561 : ntt2err:soc 836 error - operation=6, ntresnt[0]=517, ntresnt[1]=54, ntresnt[2]=0

2018-07-26 13:20:36.561 : ntt2err:exit

2018-07-26 13:20:36.571 : nttwr:exit

2018-07-26 13:20:36.571 : nspsend:0 bytes to transport

2018-07-26 13:20:36.571 : nspsend:transport write error

2018-07-26 13:20:36.571 : nspsend:error exit

2018-07-26 13:20:36.579 : nserror:entry

2018-07-26 13:20:36.579 : nserror:nsres: id=0, op=67, ns=12547, ns2=12560; nt[0]=517, nt[1]=54, nt[2]=0; ora[0]=0, ora[1]=0, ora[2]=0

2018-07-26 13:20:36.579 : nsdofls:exit (-1)

2018-07-26 13:20:36.579 : nsdo:nsctxrnk=0

2018-07-26 13:20:36.579 : nsdo:error exit

2018-07-26 13:20:36.579 : nioqrc:send failed: bl = 1, nicbl = 0

2018-07-26 13:20:36.579 : nioqper: error from nioqrc

2018-07-26 13:20:36.579 : nioqper:   ns main err code: 12547

2018-07-26 13:20:36.579 : nioqper:   ns (2)  err code: 12560

2018-07-26 13:20:36.579 : nioqper:   nt main err code: 517

2018-07-26 13:20:36.579 : nioqper:   nt (2)  err code: 54

2018-07-26 13:20:36.579 : nioqper:   nt OS   err code: 0

2018-07-26 13:20:36.579 : nioqer:entry

2018-07-26 13:20:36.579 : nioqer: incoming err = 12150

2018-07-26 13:20:36.592 : nioqce:entry

2018-07-26 13:20:36.592 : nioqce:exit

2018-07-26 13:20:36.593 : nioqer: returning err = 3135

2018-07-26 13:20:36.593 : nioqer:exit

2018-07-26 13:20:36.593 : nioqrc: returning error: 3135

Comment: This sounds like `Doc ID 1319797.1`. Can you check the size of your `listener.log` file on the server? Should be in `%ORACLE_BASE%\diag\tnslsnr\<hostname>\listener\trace\<listener_name>.log`. If it's close to 4gb, delete it or rename it.

Comment: I tried that but no luck I'm afraid.  Thanks for the suggestion though.